# Difference between "beim Essen" and "während dem Essen"

Tags: word-usage, preposition

I simply can't fathom the difference between

> beim Essen

and

> während dem Essen

Found totally nothing on google or reverso

Comment: *während* also has the meaning of "for <time unit>" in Swiss German: "Die Besprechung dauert während zwei Stunden". Not in DE or AT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your example structures are functionally equivalent.**

You asked about the difference between *beim* and *während*.

*Während* can be preposition or [conjunction](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/waehrend_als_unterdessen_wohingegen), just like the English *while*, meaning *during the time* or *whereas* respectively.
You are talking about the preposition.

The preposition *während* is governed by the genitive case (*während des Essens*), but note that it can also be [governed by the dative case](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/waehrend_binnen_inmitten) (*während dem Essen*), mostly in colloquial language. Your example is correct.

A few more examples:

> Während dem Konzert wurde bei ihm eingebrochen. (time of the concert)
>   Während der Ferien sind viele Hotels teurer als sonst. (time of holidays)

In neither of these examples could *während* be replaced with *bei* / *beim* / *bei den*, because they explicitly refer to a period of time, and the preposition *bei* cannot do that!

*Beim* is the contraction of the preposition *bei* and the article *dem* (dative singular of *der* or *das*).

The preposition *bei* (and therefore: *beim*) doesn’t refer to a pepriod of time.
Instead, it tells us about a *location* or an *event* (there are other prepositions that do this: *auf*, *in* etc.).

> Wir treffen uns beim Konzert. (event)
>   Beim Rathaus ist heute eine Demo. (location)

*Beim* is also often used with nominalized verbs, like in your example: *beim Essen*.
All verbs turned into nouns become neuter: *das Essen*, *das Laufen*, *das Naseputzen*, *das Schreiben*…

1. The preposition *bei* is governed by the dative case.
2. All verbs turned into nouns are singular and neuter (*das*).
3. *Dem* is the dative singular of *das*.
4. *Bei dem* is contracted to *beim*.

This is the reason why there are so many constructions like the one in your example.
All verbs turned into nouns take the same *beim*:

> beim Essen, beim Schlafen, beim Naseputzen

By creating the noun *Essen* from the verb *essen*, you make it into an event.

> Beim Essen wurde auch getrunken. (event)
>   Beim Tanzen hat er seine Frau kennengelernt. (event)

So, when you say

> Beim Essen…

you are actually saying: At the event of eating.
When you say

> Während dem Essen… / Während des Essens…

you actually say: While eating.

In the case of your examples, these are **functionally equivalent**.

Comment: Holy hell, that's pretty in-depth.

Answer (score 6):

Both words are very similar and can often be used interchangeably. Imho, there is a slight difference though:

### beim Essen

refers more to eating in general, e.g.

> Pack beim Essen dein Handy weg.
>
> *Put away your phone while you eat.*

or analogous to "at work"

### während des¹ Essens

refers more to a concrete event

> Während des Mittagessens fiel mir das Handy aus der Tasche.
>
> *My phone fell out of my pocket during lunch.*

analogous to "during work"

---

¹ you use genitive after *während*

Comment: Das funktioniert genauso gut anders herum: _Packe während des Essens dein Handy weg._ und _Beim Mittagessen fiel mir das Handy aus der Tasche._

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich, das würde meinem sprachgefühl widersprechen. *Packe während des Essens dein Handy weg* - eigentlich sollte man *wärend* des Essens das Handy gar nicht anfassen, es sollte schon vorher weg sein.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Ich stimme dir teilweise zu, danke für den Hinweis. Allerdings finde ich, wie ths, dass sich deine Varianten etwas weniger richtig **anfühlen**.

Comment: And is it possible to say *bei der Arbeit* and *während der Arbeit*? Just for the sake of clarification

Comment: @AndrewChem. In princple, yes, but they have possibly different meanings, depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

"Essen", in the first case, defines the *act of eating*, unless the intended meaning is "adjacent to the food/meal". Best understood as "while eating".

"während dem Essen" clearly refers to "Essen" meaning a mealtime or banquet/formal meal, so it is best understood as "during mealtime", "during the banquet". If "while eating" was to be expressed with "während", the correct phrase would be "während *des Essens*"